# What does $v=c$ in the Lorentz transformation for time tell us?

Tags: special-relativity, speed-of-light, time, inertial-frames, time-dilation

For the simpler cases as boost in the x-direction, the time dilation formula following the Lorentz transformation for time is $$\Delta t'=\gamma(\Delta t-v\frac{\Delta x}{c^2})$$Now, we observe that as $v\to c$, $\gamma\to \infty$. And we also observe that if we increase $v$, the term in brackets beside $\gamma$ decreases more rapidly than the denominator of $\gamma$ i.e., $\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}$. But if we put $v=c$ suddenly, $\gamma$ becomes undefined and the denominator of $\gamma$ and the term in brackets beside $\gamma$ becomes zero mathematically at the same time while the term in brackets was decreasing more rapidly. But while increasing $v$ to $c$ we see that $\Delta t'$ decreases and approaches zero and as we know $c$ is the maximum speed why don't we get $\Delta t'=0$ on putting $v=c$? Why do we get an indeterminate form? What is the explanation for this?

Comment: The $v=c$ frame does not exist.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You cannot boost a massive particle to the speed of light, which is what you're trying to do. The infinities you are finding when you set $v=c$ are closely related to the fact that it would take an infinite amount of energy to accelerate a massive object, like a pebble or an electron, to the speed of light. So this is a mathematical manifestation of the commonly repeated mantras that 1) nothing can go faster than the speed of light and 2) only massless particles can travel at the speed of light.

Answer (score 1):

Also, the fact that $\Delta t' \rightarrow 0$ if we formally let $v \rightarrow c$ can be interpreted as saying that no time at all passes for a particle moving at the speed of light.  Photons cannot "age" or in any other way change over time.